# (Javascript) Need help in finding error in the code with html & js

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in coding. Sorry if i'm bothering with a trivial question but currently i am stuck at finding out why the function validate2 in my code does not work. I have put my code here on codepen: https://codepen.io/anniane/pen/jvOOwe

```js
function displayOption() {
  var incometype = document.getElementById("incometype").value;
  var wage = document.getElementById("wage");
  var share = document.getElementById("share");
  var lease = document.getElementById("lease");
  var saving = document.getElementById("saving");
  var retire = document.getElementById("retire");
  var entre = document.getElementById("entre");
  var biz = document.getElementById("biz");
  var bke = document.getElementById("bke");

  if (incometype == "wage") {
    wage.style.display = "block";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "share") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "block";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "lease") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "block";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "saving") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "block";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "retire") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "block";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "entre") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "block";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "biz") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "block";
    bke.style.display = "none";
  } else if (incometype == "bke") {
    wage.style.display = "none";
    share.style.display = "none";
    lease.style.display = "none";
    saving.style.display = "none";
    retire.style.display = "none";
    entre.style.display = "none";
    biz.style.display = "none";
    bke.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function validate2() {
  var cpny = document.getElementById("cpny").value;
  var hdld = document.getElementById("hdld").value;
  var incomerate = document.getElementById("incomerate").value;
  var inctype = document.getElementById("inctype").value;
  var avginc = document.getElementById("avginc").value;
  var location = document.getElementById("location").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
  var shareorg = document.getElementById("shareorg").value;
  var sharefreq = document.getElementById("sharefreq").value;
  var shareother = document.getElementById("shareother").value;
  var leasetype = document.getElementById("leasetype").value;
  var leaseside = document.getElementById("leaseside").value;
  var leaseown = document.getElementById("leaseown").value;
  var leaseother = document.getElementById("leaseother").value;
  var savingacc = document.getElementById("savingacc").value;
  var savingbal = document.getElementById("savingbal").value;
  var savingother = document.getElementById("savingother").value;
  var retireother = document.getElementById("retireother").value;

  var errcpny;
  var errhdld;
  var errincomerate;
  var errinctype;
  var erravginc;
  var errshareorg;
  var errsharefreq;
  var errshareother;
  var errleasetype;
  var errleaseown;
  var errleaseother;
  var errsavingacc;
  var errsavingbal;
  var errsavingother;
  var errretireother;

  if (cpny == "dntn" || cpny == "hkd") {
    errcpny = "Loại hình công ty không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errcpny = "";
  }
  var errorcpny = document.getElementById("errorcpny");
  errorcpny.innerText = errcpny;
  errorcpny.style.display = "block";

  if (hdld < 3) {
    errhdld = "Thời gian công tác không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errhdld = "";
  }
  var errorhdld = document.getElementById("errorhdld");
  errorhdld.innerText = errhdld;
  errorhdld.style.display = "block";

  if (incomerate == "3") {
    errincomerate = "Tần suất nhận thu nhập không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errincomerate = "";
  }
  var errorincomerate = document.getElementById("errorincomerate");
  errorincomerate.innerText = errincomerate;
  errorincomerate.style.display = "block";

  if (inctype == "cash" && cpny == "tnhh1tv") {
    errinctype = "Hình thức nhận lương không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errinctype = "";
  }
  var errorinctype = document.getElementById("errorinctype");
  errorinctype.innerText = errinctype;
  errorinctype.style.display = "block";

  if (
    (location == "hnhcm" && status == "single" && avginc < 7) ||
    (location == "hnhcm" && status == "married" && avginc < 10) ||
    (location == "other" && status == "single" && avginc < 5) ||
    (location == "other" && status == "married" && avginc < 7)
  ) {
    erravginc = "Tổng thu nhập trung bình không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    erravginc = "";
  }
  var erroravginc = document.getElementById("erroravginc");
  erroravginc.innerText = erravginc;
  erroravginc.style.display = "block";

  if (shareorg == "2") {
    errshareorg = "Doanh nghiệp KH góp vốn không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errshareorg = "";
  }
  var errorshareorg = document.getElementById("errorshareorg");
  errorshareorg.innerText = errshareorg;
  errorshareorg.style.display = "block";

  if (sharefreq == "less") {
    errsharefreq = "Tần suất KH nhận lợi tức không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errsharefreq = "";
  }
  var errorsharefreq = document.getElementById("errorsharefreq");
  errorsharefreq.innerText = errsharefreq;
  errorsharefreq.style.display = "block";

  if (shareother == "no") {
    errshareother = "Khách hàng không có nguồn thu khác, không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errshareother = "";
  }
  var errorshareother = document.getElementById("errorshareother");
  errorshareother.innerText = errshareother;
  errorshareother.style.display = "block";

  if (leasetype == "ds" && leaseside == "ind") {
    errleasetype = "Nguồn thu từ cho thuê tài sản không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errleasetype = "";
  }
  var errorleasetype = document.getElementById("errorleasetype");
  errorleasetype.innerText = errleasetype;
  errorleasetype.style.display = "block";

  if (leaseown == "other") {
    errleaseown = "Tài sản cho thuê không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errleaseown = "";
  }
  var errorleaseown = document.getElementById("errorleaseown");
  errorleaseown.innerText = errleaseown;
  errorleaseown.style.display = "block";

  if (leaseother == "no") {
    errleaseother = "Khách hàng không có nguồn thu khác, không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errleaseother = "";
  }
  var errorleaseother = document.getElementById("errorleaseother");
  errorleaseother.innerText = errleaseother;
  errorleaseother.style.display = "block";

  if (savingacc == "other") {
    errsavingacc = "Lãi tiết kiệm từ tài khoản không gửi tại VPBank sẽ không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errsavingacc = "";
  }
  var errorsavingacc = document.getElementById("errorsavingacc");
  errorsavingacc.innerText = errsavingacc;
  errorsavingacc.style.display = "block";

  if (savingbal == "no") {
    errsavingbal = "Điều kiện về số dư bình quân không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errsavingbal = "";
  }
  var errorsavingbal = document.getElementById("errorsavingbal");
  errorsavingbal.innerText = errsavingbal;
  errorsavingbal.style.display = "block";

  if (savingother == "no") {
    errsavingother = "Khách hàng không có nguồn thu khác, không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errsavingother = "";
  }
  var errorsavingother = document.getElementById("errorsavingother");
  errorsavingother.innerText = errsavingother;
  errorsavingother.style.display = "block";

  if (retireother == "no") {
    errretireother = "Khách hàng không có nguồn thu khác, không thỏa mãn chính sách!";
  } else {
    errretireother = "";
  }
  var errorretireother = document.getElementById("errorretireother");
  errorretireother.innerText = errretireother;
  errorretireother.style.display = "block";

  if (errcpny) return false;
  if (errhdld) return false;
  if (errincomerate) return false;
  if (errinctype) return false;
  if (erravginc) return false;
  if (errshareorg) return false;
  if (errsharefreq) return false;
  if (errshareother) return false;
  if (errleasetype) return false;
  if (errleaseown) return false;
  if (errleaseother) return false;
  if (errsavingacc) return false;
  if (errsavingbal) return false;
  if (errsavingother) return false;
  if (errretireother) return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="step4.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate2()">

  <h4>Nguồn thu nhập chính của khách hàng đến từ</h4>

  <select class="category" name="incometype" id="incometype" onchange="displayOption()">
    <option value="">Hãy chọn nguồn thu chính của khách hàng</option>
    <option value="wage">Lương</option>
    <option value="share">Cổ tức</option>
    <option value="lease">Cho thuê tài sản</option>
    <option value="saving">Lãi tiền gửi</option>
    <option value="retire">Lương hưu trí</option>
    <option value="bke">Bảng kê thu nhập</option>
    <option value="entre">Doanh nghiệp do khách hàng làm chủ</option>
    <option value="biz">Hộ kinh doanh</option>

  </select>
  <div id="wage" style="display:none">
    <h4>Khách hàng đang làm việc tại loại hình công ty nào?</h4>

    <div id="errorcpny" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div id="errorhdld" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div id="errorincomerate" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div id="errorinctype" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>
    <div id="erroravginc" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="cpny" id="cpny">
      <option value="dnnn">Doanh nghiệp NN</option>
      <option value="tnhh2tv">Công ty TNHH 2 thành viên trở lên</option>
      <option value="ctcp">Công ty cổ phần</option>
      <option value="dntn">Doanh nghiệp tư nhân</option>
      <option value="tnhh1tv">Công ty TNHH 1 thành viên</option>
      <option value="hkd">Hộ kinh doanh</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <h4>Khách hàng làm tại công ty trên được bao lâu?</h4>

    <input type="number" name="hdld" id="hdld"> tháng

    <br>

    <h4>Khách hàng nhận thu nhập bao lâu một lần?</h4>

    <select class="category" name="incomerate" id="incomerate">
      <option value="1">1 đến 3 tháng/lần</option>
      <option value="2">3 đến 12 tháng/lần</option>
      <option value="3">trên 12 tháng/lần</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Khách hàng nhận lương theo hình thức nào</h4>

    <select class="category" name="inctype" id="inctype">
      <option value="cash">Tiền mặt</option>
      <option value="payroll">Chuyển khoản</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Tổng thu nhập trung bình (bao gồm lương và các khoản trợ cấp) của cả 2 vợ chồng trong vòng 3 tháng gần nhất</h4>

    <input type="number" name="avginc" id="avginc"> triệu VND

    <h4>Nơi cư trú & làm việc</h4>

    <select class="category" name="location" id="location">
      <option value="hnhcm">Hà Nội & Hồ Chí Minh</option>
      <option value="other">Các tỉnh/thành phố khác</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Tình trạng hôn nhân</h4>

    <select class="category" name="status" id="status">
      <option value="single">Độc thân</option>
      <option value="married">Đã kết hôn</option>
    </select>

    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="share" style="display:none">
    <h4>Công ty KH góp vốn thành lập được bao lâu?</h4>

    <select class="category" name="shareorg" id="shareorg">
      <option value="2">Dưới 2 năm</option>
      <option value="more">Từ 2 năm trở lên</option>
    </select>
    <div id="errorshareorg" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <br>
    <h4>Tần suất khách hàng nhận cổ tức/lợi nhuận?</h4>
    <div id="errorsharefreq" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="sharefreq" id="sharefreq">
      <option value="2">Ít nhất 02 lần trong 02 năm gần nhất</option>
      <option value="less">Ít hơn 02 lần trong 02 năm gần nhất</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <h4>Khách hàng có nguồn thu khác không?</h4>
    <div id="errorshareother" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="shareother" id="shareother">
      <option value="yes">Có</option>
      <option value="no">Không</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Tổng thu nhập của khách hàng từ lợi nhuận cổ tức trong 3 kì gần nhất:</h4>

    <input type="number" name="shareavg" id="shareavg"> triệu VND

    <br>
  </div>
  <div id="lease" style="display:none">
    <h4>Tài sản cho thuê là bất động sản hay động sản?</h4>
    <div id="errorleasetype" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="leasetype" id="leasetype">
      <option value="bds">Bất động sản</option>
      <option value="ds">Động sản</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <h4>Bên thuê tài sản là tổ chức hay cá nhân?</h4>

    <select class="category" name="leaseside" id="leaseside">
      <option value="org">Tổ chức</option>
      <option value="ind">Cá nhân</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Tài sản thuộc quyền sở hữu của KH hay người khác</h4>
    <div id="errorleaseown" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="leaseown" id="leaseown">
      <option value="self">Của khách hàng</option>
      <option value="other">Của người khác/theo ủy quyền của người khác</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Khách hàng có nguồn thu khác không?</h4>
    <div id="errorleaseother" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="leaseother" id="leaseother">
      <option value="yes">Có</option>
      <option value="no">Không</option>
    </select>

    <br>

  </div>
  <div id="saving" style="display:none">
    <h4>STK khách hàng mở tại VPBank hay nơi khác?</h4>
    <div id="errorsavingacc" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="savingacc" id="savingacc">
      <option value="vpb">VPBank</option>
      <option value="other">Nơi khác</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Số dư bình quân của tài khoản tiết kiệm có được duy trì liên tục tối thiểu 3 tháng tính đến thời điểm đề xuất vay vốn không?</h4>
    <div id="errorsavingbal" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="savingbal" id="leasebal">
      <option value="yes">Có</option>
      <option value="no">Không</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    <h4>Khách hàng có nguồn thu khác không?</h4>
    <div id="errorsavingother" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="savingother" id="savingother">
      <option value="yes">Có</option>
      <option value="no">Không</option>
    </select>

    <br>

  </div>
  <div id="retire" style="display:none">
    <h4>Khách hàng có nguồn thu khác không?</h4>

    <div id="errorretireother" style="color: red; display:none; font-weight: bold;"></div>

    <select class="category" name="retireother" id="retireother">
      <option value="yes">Có</option>
      <option value="no">Không</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Tiếp tục">
</form>
```

Looking forward to get an answer and learn more about coding. Thanks alot!

Comment: What's the error you get and when does it occur?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and welcome to coding :) However it's very hard to help without knowing what exactly is going wrong with your code, especially since there's a whole lot of it. Can you elaborate on what in particular isn't working? What's the expected output?

Comment: well I expected when you make input that will cause the javascript to "return false" through those if statements, the page will not continue when you press "submit" button, but it stills continue even though I expected it to be stopped.

Comment: Does it not work for _any_ of those errors, or is there a particular condition that doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: yes currently it does not work for any of those "err" conditions

Comment: I believe this whole buch of code could be rewritten in like 10 lines or so. But man, just pasting 500 lines of code and saying "It doesn't work" is not really the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your pen with your browser's developer tools up, you'll find this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

on the line

```
var savingbal = document.getElementById("savingbal").value;
```

Because there's an error in the `onsubmit` handler, it won't `return false`, so the submit action succeeds.

The problem seems to be a copy-paste one – the `select` with the name `savingbal` still has the ID `leasebal`, so `document.getElementById("savingbal")` returns `null`.

```
<select class="category" name="savingbal" id="leasebal">
```

Fixing this to

```
<select class="category" name="savingbal" id="savingbal">
```

seems to make the `onsubmit` handler work.

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! Sorry for causing trouble over a simple problem like this!